# How can I make drawer view appear when overflow icon in toolbar is clicked?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

**Problem:**  I am using a custom Toolbar.  When I click the overflow icon button, it opens the menu item, but it does so separately from my Navigation Drawer.  For example, if I slide my Navigation Drawer open and then click on the overflow icon in the toolbar it will open the menu again over the Navigation Drawer.

**What I have tried:** I have tried to move around the structure of how the views are in my MainActivity.XML  but nothing seems to change it.  I also added the toolbar to the `mMenuToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);` but that just creates a new hamburger icon to the left of the toolbar and when I click on it, it crashes the app.

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer_layout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/wf_logo_text"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar.XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:id="@+id/toolBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wf_logo_text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**menu.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

<item android:id="@+id/locations"
    android:title="ATMs/Locations"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:checkable="false" />
</group>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mMenuToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Sets toolbar
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Drawable drawable = 

 ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
  R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);

    // Main Activity DrawerLayout with Toggle
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_drawer_layout);

    // Menu Toggle Button
    mMenuToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 
R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mMenuToggle);
    mMenuToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

**What happens and what I want to happen:** I just want to use the same overflow icon that is created with the custom Toolbar on the right side and to be able to click on it and have it open the Navigation drawer instead of a separate menu.

Comment: I think `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` should be root container here .. Not sure though..